# Number of Linear Transformations having same Kernel space dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T:V->W.  Is it possible to have multiple T's that have the same dim(ker(T)) dimensions of the kernel of T ?

If not why ?

Comment: If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then there are only finitely many possible dimensions for the kernel, but infinitely many linear transformations. Therefore, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at an example to understand the question a bit better.

Let's for simplicity work with $\mathbb R$-vector spaces, i.e. $V = \mathbb R^n$ and $W = \mathbb R^m$ - when I picture things, I like to think $V = \mathbb R^2 = W$. So we just have a 2-dimensional plane.

What's a linear map $V \to W$ now? It's just some function $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $T(\lambda a+b) = \lambda T(a) + T(b)$ for any $\lambda \in R$ and $a,b \in \mathbb R^2$. It means exactly that I can define $T$ on basis vectors and this will determine how $T$ acts on all of $\mathbb R^2$. Let's pick $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ as a basis here; it doesn't really matter what basis we pick, but this one is familiar and easy. Write $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ to mean $x(1,0) + y(0,1)$. Suppose we set $T((1,0)) =w_1$ and $T((0,1)) = w_2$. Then
$$T((x,y)) = T(x(1,0) + y(0,1)) = xT(1,0) + yT(0,1) = xw_1 + yw_2. $$
Hence $T$ really is determined by the images we picked for our basis elements.

Now how can we picture such a map? The thing to note here is that the image of $T$ is spanned by $w_1$ and $w_2$ (which in this situation are elements of $\mathbb R^2$). This means that the image of $T$ is either $\mathbb R^2$ (if $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent), some one-dimensional subspace isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ (if $w_1$ and $w_2$ are non-zero and are scalar multiples of each other), or zero, if $w_1 = 0 = w_2$.

This also gives us a way of mapping $\mathbb R^2$ linearly onto any line through the origin: say we want the line $ay = bx$. Then we just pick $w_1 = (b,a) = w_2$, i.e. we define $T$ through $T((1,0)) = (b,a) = T((0,1))$. In this case the image of the map is one-dimensional.

Now the rank-nullity theorem says that if $T: V \to W$ is a linear map, and $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, then $\dim(\ker T) + \dim(\text{im } T) = n$. In the case of our example, $n = 2$. Now if $T$ is *any* transformation which maps $\mathbb R^2$ onto a line, we have $\dim(\text{im } T) = 1$, and hence $\dim(\ker T ) = 1$. But of course there are infinitely many lines through the origin, so we can find infinitely many linear maps with the same kernel dimension.

Similarly, we can find infinitely many distinct linear maps with kernel dimension zero: these correspond to different choices of linearly independent $w_1, w_2$. However, there is only one linear map with kernel dimension $2$, because we'd have to choose $w_1 = 0 = w_2$.

I believe this answers your question and hopefully gives you some insight about kernels. What I want you to take away from this is that $\dim(\ker T))$ is a very *coarse* piece of information about $T$: it tells us roughly what $T$ does, namely it tells us what dimension the image of $T$ has, but it by no means determines $T$.

Comment: In essence just giving that information tells you that infinite such linear transformations are possible ?

Comment: If you mean that giving the dimension of the kernel of a linear transformation still leaves you with infinitely many valid options, then yes, under the assumption that: 1. the dimension of the kernel is non-zero, and 2. the ground field we are working over is infinite.

Comment: Kernel of dimension zero still leaves infinitely many linear transformations (assuming the ground field is infinite and the domain is nontrivial); I think you meant to exclude the case where the kernel has *codimension* zero, that is, when the kernel is the entire domain.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson You're right, thanks for spotting that :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can for example use $T_1:y=x$ and $T_2:y=2x$.

$V=W=\Bbb{R}$, $dim(ker(T_1))=dim(ket(T_2))=0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a $n\geq 1$ dimensional vector space, Suppose $dim(ker(T))=m \leq n$. Pick a basis $B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ for $V$ and a basis $C=\{w_1,...,w_s\}$ for $W$. Select any $m$ vectors $\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ in $B$. Construct any $H:V \rightarrow W$ such that $H$ sends all $u_i$'s to 0 and  maps the remaining vectors in $B$ injectively to some vectors in $C$. The resulting map has a kernel spanned by $\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ and hence will have dimension $m$.  The number of maps like this is $\binom{n}{m}*(n-m)*s$.